# qt opencv qt LNK1181 opencv_ffmpeg331_64.dll.lib

Tags: qt, opencv

I want to use opencv 3.3.1 with qt creator. I think configuration is correct but I always get same error:

> LNK1181 opencv_ffmpeg331_64.dll.lib.

I can't tell to compiler this file is dll not a lib.
The Qmake file is:

```
INCLUDEPATH += D:\opencv\opencv3\build\include
LIBS += -LD:\opencv\opencv3\build\x64\vc14\bin -lopencv_ffmpeg331_64.dll -lopencv_world331.dll
LIBS += -LD:\opencv\opencv3\build\x64\vc14\lib -lopencv_world331.lib
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to link to ffmpeg. Also you're linking twice to opencv_world

Comment: Also, you normally link to the .lib and have the .dll for runtime. This means in LIBS you should put your .lib files only and copy the dlls needed to the folder with the .exe or put the folder where your dll are as environment variable.